# Uploading multiple files in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, upload

I'm working on uploading multiple files but I'm not passing the params correctly between the form and the controller - not quite sure what I'm missing.

Form is pretty simple:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => :admins, :action => :upload_json}, {:multipart => true, :method => :post, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal"}}) do %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Data</legend>
    <ol class="field-list">
      <li>
        <label for="data-file">JSON File</label>
        <%= file_field_tag 'jsonfileupload', multiple: true %>
      </li>
    </ol>


    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
    </div>

  </fieldset>

<% end %>
```

In the controller, I'm just doing this to see what's passed:

```
@output = params[:jsonfileupload]
```

In the view, I just do a `debug` to see what's returned, and it only pulls the last file of any set of selected files.

```
#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f95d0c21010 @original_filename="4987.json", @content_type="application/json", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"jsonfileupload\"; filename=\"4987.json\"\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/0p/6lq88m950mgftng1qm1w63_8000194/T/RackMultipart20121114-389-t9l7vs>>
```

Not sure what I'm missing to get it to return all the files selected. Thanks for the help!

Comment: you miss `original_filename`, change this `@output = params[:jsonfileupload]` to `@output = params[:jsonfileupload].original_filename`

Comment: Thanks @Kien Thanh. I'm still not able to see multiple files if I select multiple files. I'm only getting the last file selected.

Comment: I should note, this form isn't tied to a model as it's just doing some temporary data loading and then being discarded.

Comment: I thought, theoretically, by passing `multiple: true` that they'd be sent as an array of files. Then I could loop through the array in the controller.

Comment: can you show your render html and controller?

Comment: Unless you're using some client-side scripting it's not possible to upload multiple files to a single file field AFAIK. Have you checked out JQuery File Upload? It's quite simple to implement. There's a pro edition railscast episode that will walk you through every step involved.

Comment: Thanks Kien. Cyle: I tried the railscasts episode but couldn't get it to work. Maybe missed a step - will try again.

Comment: have you loop `@output.each` when upload?

Comment: I was able to solve this by adjusting the `file_field_tag` to: `<%= file_field_tag 'jsonfileupload[]', multiple: true %>`. Info was then passed as an array and I'm successfully looping through it. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adjusting the `file_field_tag` to: `<%= file_field_tag 'jsonfileupload[]', multiple: true %>`