# How do I upload multiple files in Rails 4 (with jquery)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, file-upload, ruby-on-rails-4

I added an upload form so people can upload HTML files to my site. How do I allow multiple uploads at once? I added the [jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) gem which lets the user select multiple files. However, only one file gets processed by the server. How do I fix this?

**More Details**

My code is below, based on this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload?view=asciicast). Note I'm not dealing with a model in the form, so I use field_tags instead. I didn't add name to `file_field_tag`, since it's name didn't change after adding files, though that may be part of the problem.

```
<%= form_tag import_items_path, multipart: true, id: "upload" do %>
    <%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>
    <%= submit_tag "Import" %>
<% end %>
```

And here's some the JS for the fileupload jQuery:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#upload').fileupload
```

When I add 2 files and click upload, only 1 file gets processed. Here's the log:

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "file"=> #< ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x... @tempfile=#< Tempfile:/var/folders/gl/...>, @original_filename="sample.html", @content_type="text/html",... name=\"file\"; filename=\"sample.html\"...}

I tried ajaxifying the form, but that didn't help either. How can I get jquery-fileupload-rails in Rails 4 to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change `<%= file_field_tag :file, multiple: true %>` to `<%= file_field_tag 'files[]', multiple: true %>` it should work.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380432/uploading-multiple-files-in-rails-3) related SO post.

Comment: Thanks. After doing that, I just needed to change the backend to deal with an array (as opposed to the repeated JS calls the railscast has).